# "for-in" statement syntax with multiple elements syntax issues , The same syntax works in python but not in dart?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, for-loop

```
var pairs = [
  [1, 2],
  [2, 2],
  [2, 3],
  [4, 4]
];

count4(x, y, pairs) {
  var same_count = 0;
  for (final x,final y in pairs) {
      if (x == y) {
        same_count += 1;
      }
    }
  return same_count;
}
```

This code with similar syntax works in python, but i am trying to implement it in dart and running into all sorts of errors. Any ideas how i can re-write the syntax to make it work?

Comment: this is not supported on dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (final x,final y in pairs)` is **destructuring** every element in the list and this is not supported in dart *yet*.

So you need to rewrite it like following:

```
count4(x, y, pairs) {
  var same_count = 0;
  for (final pair in pairs) {
      if (pair[0] == pair[1]) {
        same_count += 1;
      }
    }
  return same_count;
}
```

By the way, you apparently don't need `x,y` as parameters if you don't use them.

Comment: Thanks a lot you are correct! and yes i dont need x,y so mistake on my part!